# How to make Word automatically restore the documents that it had open before a reboot?

Tags: windows-7, windows, microsoft-word-2010, reboot, restore

I normally have over a dozen documents open in Microsoft Word 2010.
It takes quite a while to reopen those files using the File/Recent feature.
I'd like Word to automatically restore the open files after a reboot.
And I know this isn't just wishful thinking because Windows Updates
does exactly that:  After installing updates, Microsoft Update restores
Word with all the files that were open before the reboot.

Answer (score 2):

The functionality WU uses to do that is available to you via the `shutdown` command.  Specifically by using the `/g` option.

From `shutdown /?`:

> /g         Shutdown and restart the computer. After the system is
>               rebooted, restart any registered applications.

So, run `shutdown /g /t 00` and you system will reboot right then, and restore the applications, at least ones that support it (like Word, IE, etc.), after you log back in.

If you want to make it into an icon you could just put that command into a batch file, and save it on your desktop so you can double click it when you want to reboot.

Comment: Good stuff. Something I notice is that it can take quite some time for Windows to get around to restarting the applications - i.e., the first time you try it, you may think it has failed...unless you wait a while.